# Quando o destruidor de um objeto é chamado no C++?

Tags: c++, objetos, destrutor

Vamos supor que eu tenho uma função:

```
std::string empty_string() {
    std::string x{ "" };
    return x;
}
```

Por mais que pareça normal, fica meio confuso quando nós pensamos:

**Quando o destruidor do objeto `x` é chamado?**

Observe:

```
std::string empty_string() {
    std::string x{ "" };
    //se o destruidor for chamado aqui, x vai ser deletado antes de ser retornado 
    return x;
    //qualquer coisa depois do return é inutil
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em condições normais o destrutor é chamado entre o `return` visto no código e a última instrução que calculou algo (inclusive uma que esteja no `return`). O compilador insere algo ali. O que talvez você não saiba é que o `return` é um código que faz algumas coisas:

- uma delas é **resultar algo**, ou seja, ele pode executar uma expressão, no seu caso é só pegar o valor de uma variável, e "enviar" para quem chamou, muito provavelmente em um *slot* reservado em uma expressão na função chamadora, ou até mais comum atribuída para uma variável, que não deixa de ser um *slot* reservado.
- outra é a **volta do controle de execução do código para o local chamador**, o que de fato chamamos retorno.

Ente um e outro o compilador colocaria a chamada do destrutor da *string*.

Não enxergue o seu código como algo plano que uma linha é uma coisa sendo executada.

Dito tudo isso, não há necessidade de chamada de destrutor nesse caso e por isso nada será inserido neste código. Há a inserção de um código de cópia do valor, porque não é para destruir nada, o objeto precisa continuar vivo porque será usado na função chamadora. Há um `move` e não um `delete`, então ele copia o ponteiro para o objeto, e mantém o objeto vivo, e a chamadora é que poderá, ou não, destruir o objeto. Em algum momento é preciso destruir, quando não houver referência para ele.

Não sei se é de Portugal e lá é usado diferente, no Brasil usamos o termo destrutor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero, o comportamento de destrutores tanto de objetos quanto ponteiro de objetos é o mesmo?