# Dúvida sobre função em C++ que funciona como um destrutor?

Tags: c++, classes, destrutor

Entendi todo o código abaixo porém em determinada parte a pessoa cita algo como destrutor? O que é isso? Para que serve?

Seria essa parte aqui:

```
~Vetor() {
    delete [] vet_pos;
    delete [] vet;  }
```

Porque tem esse `~` ao lado da função? Mais parece um construtor!

```
// Sobrecarregando o operador de índice: []

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> // função exit()
using namespace std;

class Vetor
{
private:
    int *vet, *vet_pos;
    int max;

public:
    Vetor(int max = 100)
    {
        if(max < 0)
        {
            cerr << "Erro: limite maximo menor do que 0." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(max > 1000000)
        {
            cerr << "Erro: limite maximo maior do que 1000000." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        this->max = max;

        // alocar espaço
        vet = (int*)malloc(max * sizeof(int));
        vet_pos = (int*)malloc(max * sizeof(int));

        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            vet_pos[i] = 0;
    }


    ~Vetor()
    {
        delete [] vet_pos;
        delete [] vet;
    }


    bool inserir(int e, int pos)
    {
        if(pos < max && pos >= 0)
        {
            vet[pos] = e;
            vet_pos[pos] = 1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    int& operator[](int i)
    {
        if(i < 0 || i >= max)
        {
            cerr << "Erro: acesso invalido ao vetor.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(vet_pos[i] == 0)
        {
            cerr << "Erro: nessa posicao nao existe elemento.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        return vet[i];
    }



    int tam()
    {
        int cont = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            if(vet_pos[i] == 1)
                cont++;
        }
        return cont;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Vetor v(10);

    if(v.inserir(10, 0))
        cout << "Elemento inserido com sucesso!\n";
    else
        cout << "Erro ao inserir o elemento.\n";

    if(v.inserir(11, 2))
        cout << "Elemento inserido com sucesso!\n";
    else
        cout << "Erro ao inserir o elemento.\n";

    if(v.inserir(12, 10))
        cout << "Elemento inserido com sucesso!\n";
    else
        cout << "Erro ao inserir o elemento.\n";

    cout << "Primeiro elemento: " << v[0] << endl;
    cout << "Segundo elemento: " << v[2] << endl;
    //cout << "Terceiro elemento: " << v[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que serve um destrutor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75613/para-que-serve-um-destrutor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ é uma linguagem que dá liberdade para fazer coisas poderosas e flexíveis. E com isso exige muita responsabilidade para gerir todos os recursos.

Quando você instancia um objeto existem basicamente duas operações: a **alocação** que é feita pelo operador [`new`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237588/101), e esse pode ser personalizado no tipo que está criando com sobrecarga de operadores; e a **construção** que é personalizado nos [métodos construtores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), que são métodos estáticos, ou seja, fazem parte do tipo e que vão inicializar os dados no objeto sendo criado. Além da inicialização de dados pode executar certos algoritmos e trabalhar com recursos externos à aplicação, como serviços do sistema operacional por exemplo.

Esse objeto tem um [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) determinado por uma série de fatores. No momento que o objeto deve deixar de existir se tiver **um** método destrutor ele é chamado (é colocado pelo compilador no local adequado, ou é invocado pela biblioteca ou chamado manualmente pelo programador). Esse é método, que é virtual, pode, ou até deve, liberar os recursos adquiridos externamente, executar alguns algoritmos de finalização e liberar a memória alocada através do [`delete`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152765/101). Caso não faça isso terá recursos "pendurados" e [vazamento de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174916/101). Então sem este método ou sem ele fazer as operações adequadas você terá problemas.

O `~` como prefixo no nome foi convencionado para ser o destrutor, só para diferenciar do construtor que tem o nome do tipo igual ao destrutor.

No seu exemplo ele está liberando a memória de dois vetores. Mas esse código é mal feito. Nunca aloque por um método e libere por outro. No caso foi alocado com `malloc()`, então deveria usar `free()`. Ou então deveria ter alocado com `new` para liberar com `delete` que é o mais correto em C++. Mesmo a parte mais parecido com C++ usa um estilo dos anos 90, C++ mudou muito de lá pra cá. O código foi escrito por alguém que não entende C++ direito.

Veja [Quando o destruidor de um objeto é chamado no C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321651/101). Ou em um contexto mais abstrato do que eles são: [Para que serve um destrutor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75613/101).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero, sua resposta me fez entender como funciona todo o processo corretamente.

Comment: Mas somente para concluir, o destrutor só passa ser destrutor caso ele venha precedido de ~ antes do método ? Claro que precisa do delete dentro do método para funcionar mas ficou essa dúvida ainda. Obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Resumidamente:

O destrutor é o contrário do construtor.

Enquanto uma função construtora de determinada classe é chamada no momento em que uma instância daquela classe é criada (objeto), a função destrutora é chamada quando o objeto é destruído.

Para maiores detalhes, leia a resposta do Maniero, que sempre é mais completa!

Comment: Obrigado Pedro pela ajuda :)

Comment: A linguagem C++ é muito ampla e sempre descubro coisas novas que ajudam a entender mais sobre como programação funciona.